# NameError: name 'cbor' is not defined

Tags: python, cbor

I used

```
cbor_payload = cbor.dumps(cert_payload)
```

This leads to the

```
NameError: name 'cbor' is not defined
```

message. (cbor was already installed via pip install before.)

Any hints?

Comment: Did you import it?

Comment: yeah, i forgot it. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem. Added it as an actual answer to this question (as opposed to a comment).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use `import cbor` at the top of your code to actually load it into Python.